# To access request parameter in socket.on function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'am beginner of node.js,Sorry if I went wrong.

To get the parameter passed in URL like localhost:3000?id=man&fm=gilli I used

```
   app.get('/',function(req, res){
     var now = req.query.id;

     res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');

   });
```

My doubt is I want to access fm in socket.on function,for that I have tried like this

```
            io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){

                socket.nickname = req.query.fm;   //here I accessed it  
            users[socket.nickname] = socket;

        });
```

But it getting error that:

```
        req is not defined.
```

A condition here is we should not store fm parameter in global variable,Means we have to directly access the parameter passed in url in io.socket function.

i.e:In the below code fm should not be accessed like id parameter.

My total code is:

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    users = {},
now,
other;

    server.listen(3000);





        app.get('/',function(req, res){
             now = req.query.id;

             res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');

        });   

       io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){

              socket.nickname = now; // parameter id stored here using a global variable

               users[socket.nickname] = socket;





socket.on('send message',function(data, callback){
    var msg = data;


         var name = req.query.fm;    //here I got error
         var msg = msg;
         if(name in users){

                 }else{
         callback('Error enter a valid user.');
         }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement an authorization.

> In Express, when a socket connects, we don’t know which session it belongs to by default, meaning we can’t do anything private with that connection.

- [LearnBoost / socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing)
- [Authorizing and handshaking with Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106861/socket-io-authorization-nodejs)
- [A blog post with an implementation](http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth)
- [Another blog post with an implementation](http://notjustburritos.tumblr.com/post/22682186189/socket-io-and-express-3)